# Realtional Databases and Query

Tags: c, database, struct

i wanna try do some query operations on relational databases.for example

```
relation cars

    brandname     type     year   
       acura        suv       2012
        bmw          sedan     2013
```

and/or

```
relation transport

transport vehicle       capacity    ticketprice
bus                          40        30
airplane                   300         500
taxi                          3        125

in this database has up to 100 relations.
each relation could has 10 attributes.
each relation could has 10000 row data.
```

in this database there is a one text file. this file,
2
cars
transport

first line how any relation have in this file? and other lines name of relations.

there are 2 different file for each relation. first one text file,

```
3
brandname  String  20
type       String  10
year       Int     4
```

first line is how many attribute in this relation table
other lines attributes and types(string/integer) and size of attributes (bytes)

second file is binary file , there is an information about each row data. "acura   suv 2012" but its binary.

So,

I'm thinking like that,

first i have to create structs, like,

```
struct relation{
char attribute[10];
char row[10000];
}

struct row {
char type[2]; //string or integer
char title[???];   //i think i have to read from binary file how many title in this file  ??
long size;   //how many bytes size of each attribute
}
```

but i'm not sure my idea is true or not.

Comment: You are asking too many questions in one post.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on how to write good questions.

Comment: @JimGarrison My problem is actually that I can't decipher what his actual question is. ccc, you have explained about your problem but not clearly asked your Question. Please rephrase more clearly your question

Comment: sorry about that i wanna just ask my struct definitions is true?

Answer (score 0):

You could model your C data structures loosely based on the file structures.

```
struct attribute
{
    char title[17+1]; // or whatever the max. title string length; e. g. "year"
    char type;
    long size;
    unsigned char **data; // dynamically allocate data[0] up to data[10000-1]
};

struct relation
{
    char name[9+1];   // e. g. "cars", "transport"
    int how_many_attributes;
    struct attribute att[10]; // up to 10
};

struct database
{
    int how_many_relations;
    struct relation rel[100]; // up to 100
};
```